# Use Node js with mysql for onclick function

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have tried to show sql query result on click a button in node js
Like on click a button, it show the result of sql query below that button

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: @KumariNisha SQL & Node.js are very broad technologies, and software development is a subject that humanity is far from finished writing. You have to much, much, much, more precise when asking a question Kumari. Please try to describe what you are doing. And always share the part of the code relevant to what you are asking.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.